# git removal script throwing error: syntax error near unexpected token `('

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, git

I've got the below one-liner I use to cleanup my local Git repo.

```
git branch -r | awk '{print $1}' | egrep -v -f /dev/fd/0 <(git branch -vv | grep origin) | awk '{print $1}' | xargs git branch -D
```

I'm aware of its dangers but I wanted to stick it in a bash script however when I run it I get:

```
git_cleanup.sh: line 2: syntax error near unexpected token `('
git_cleanup.sh: line 2: `git branch -r | awk '{print $1}' | egrep -v -f /dev/fd/0 <(git branch -vv | grep origin) | awk '{print $1}' | xargs git branch -D'
```

I thought maybe it's an extglob issue but when I check extglob from bash it shows it as `off`:

```
$ shopt extglob
extglob         off
```

Comment: Can you please tell what you want to achieve in terms of _git_? Like _"I want to remove all branches with property X"_ or something like that? I'm asking because the git command `branch` is not meant to be used in scripts. It's a so-called _porcellain_ command that looks nice but may look different the next day (aka release).

Comment: That error is exactly what I'd expect *if bash is being run in POSIX conformant mode* - do you happen to have a `POSIXLY_CORRECT` environment variable in effect?

Comment: @steeldriver You are targeting the `<(...)` thing, right? That's a pure bashism, afaik. Still. There are better ways to remove branches NOT from origin (or whatever the code is supposed to do).

Comment: @PerlDuck process substitution originated in ksh I think (and is supported in ksh and zsh as well as bash). It would cause a slightly different error if run in dash (`Syntax error: "(" unexpected`)

Comment: It looks like the OP is on a system whose `/bin/sh` isn't `dash` but `bash` which, when called `sh`, runs in POSIX mode. Leon, next time, please ask on [unix.se] instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are running a *bash* script as an *sh* script. You haven't shown your actual script, but based on the error, I am guessing you either have an `sh` shebang:

```
#!/bin/sh
```

Or you are calling the script with `sh` instead of `bash`:

```
sh yourScript.sh
```

The `<()` operator you are using is a bash feature and isn't available in the `sh` shell (which is a basic shell called `dash` on Ubuntu systems). To fix this, just replace your shebang line with:

```
#!/bin/bash
```

Or, if you are calling the script manually, use `bash`:

```
bash yourScript.sh
```

To illustrate:

```
$ cat script.sh
wc < <(echo foo)
```

Now, if I run this with bash:

```
$ bash ./script.sh 
      1       1       4
```

But with `sh`:

```
$ sh ./script.sh 
./script.sh: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `<'
./script.sh: line 1: `wc < <(echo foo)'
```

---

Actually, the error you get is not what `dash` would print, so I assume you aren't actually running this on an Ubuntu system. In this case, it makes no difference since the same basic issue would happen on Ubuntu as well, but next time, please ask on http://linux.stackexchange.com instead.

Comment: many thanks @terdon, can't believe I overlooked something so obvious, swapping the header from `#!/bin/sh` to `#!/bin/bash` resolved the issue.